# GridView scrolling out of view and scroll bars disappears on Android

Tags: android

I have a very strange bug in my gridview

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
```

/>

I displays images in a gridview and can scroll up and down

However if I scroll fast upwards and the top line of images pass the bottom of the screen and I can no longer scroll and am just left with a empty screen

Any ideas?

Comment: I encountered exactly the same issue last week. In my case I think it had something to do with trying to cramp too many/large elements into a single grid item. For example: I was displaying some text next to an image (asynchronously downloaded), but the latter had enormous dimensions, screwing up the layout and causing a weird 'overscroll' leaving nothing but an empty screen. Resizing the icons solved this problem for me.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: I also faced similar problem. For my case the size of the image was very large for gridview to load. So, try resizing the images into small sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set LayoutParams in you GetView code e.g

```
mFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(175, 175));
```

I'm inflating frame layout in GridView, Width of the columns of GridView is 175. I think problem arises when you scroll than height and width of inflating view exceeds the width of column's width.

Correct me if I'm wrong. But this piece of code solved my problem.